# Why would I extend AppCompatActivity instead of Activity for Android 4.0 and Up?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

When I wrote my first Android app for Android 2.2 my activities had to use `extends AppCompatActivity` because fragments where not available in Android 2.2.

Today many apps written for Android 4.0 and newer use `extends AppCompatActivity` instead of `extends Activity`. Since Android 4 supports fragments and styles is there still a need to use `AppCompatActivity`?

The Android Studio wizard also generates code for `AppCompatActivity`.

Note: this question is **not** about "AppCompat" in general (like Android 6 permission support, it is only about activity and fragment handling.

[update]
What my question really was about **concreate** examples of what an AppCompatActivity Activity under android-4.0 can do than an android-4.0 Actrivity with `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.XXX)` cannot do. All i found that [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) adds get/setSupportXXXX

The only concrete example i got so far is use Material Design views.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` enables many of the backwards compatibility features in a transparent manner. For example, implements Material Design views and features not available in 4.0. So, it's still a good practice to use it.

Comment: any explainations for the downvotes? whould reformulate the question to "what are the downsides to not use AppCompatActivity" better?

Comment: Today many apps written for Android 4.0 and newer use extends AppCompatActivity. Are you sure???

Answer (score 8):

The AppCompatActivity gets improvements periodically (support library updates). The normal Activity class is static, the code was written once and never updated.

So whatever the Android version, AppCompatActivity is almost always better, faster, newer.

Also, other features are added later, in version Android 5 etc. that need to be back ported to 4.0.

Comment: you missed the part where AppCompat is backward compatibility, and appcompat themes require AppCompatActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

Since 2017 the AppCompat-7 library is essential for Activities and Fragments to host  [Lifecycle-Aware Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html)